# Scrollable tab bar with FreshTabbedNavigationContainer

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, freshmvvm

With FreshMVVM's `FreshTabbedNavigationContainer` all tabs want to be visible simultaneously and truncated:

[image]

I want them to be full width and scrollable like with regular `TabbedPage`:

[image]

I don't actually have so many tabs. This is just an example to show what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use CustomRednerer.
For example:
 In  Droid project:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ScrollableTabbedPage), typeof(ScrollableTabbedPageRenderer))]
namespace ScrollableFreshTabbed.Droid
{
    class ScrollableTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
    {
        public ScrollableTabbedPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
        {

        }
        public override void OnViewAdded(Android.Views.View child)
        {
            base.OnViewAdded(child);
            var tabLayout = child as TabLayout;
            if (tabLayout != null)
            {
                tabLayout.TabMode = TabLayout.ModeScrollable;
            }
        }    
    }
}
```

In the Portable project:

```
public class ScrollableTabbedPage :  FreshTabbedNavigationContainer
{
    public ScrollableTabbedPage ()
    {

    }
}
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
        public App ()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var tabbedNavigation = new ScrollableTabbedPage();
            tabbedNavigation.AddTab<QuotePageModel>("Contacts", null);
            tabbedNavigation.AddTab<QuotePageModel>("Contacts", null);
            tabbedNavigation.AddTab<QuotePageModel>("Contacts", null);
            tabbedNavigation.AddTab<QuotePageModel>("Contacts", null);
            tabbedNavigation.AddTab<QuotePageModel>("Contacts", null);
            tabbedNavigation.AddTab<QuotePageModel>("Contacts", null);
            tabbedNavigation.AddTab<QuotePageModel>("Contacts", null);
            tabbedNavigation.AddTab<QuotePageModel>("Contacts", null);
            tabbedNavigation.AddTab<QuotePageModel>("Contacts", null);
            tabbedNavigation.AddTab<QuotePageModel>("Contacts", null);
            tabbedNavigation.AddTab<QuotePageModel>("Contacts", null);
            tabbedNavigation.AddTab<QuotePageModel>("Contacts", null);
            tabbedNavigation.AddTab<QuotePageModel>("Contacts", null);
            tabbedNavigation.AddTab<QuotePageModel>("Contacts", null);
            tabbedNavigation.AddTab<QuotePageModel>("Contacts", null);
            tabbedNavigation.AddTab<QuotePageModel>("Contacts", null);

            MainPage = tabbedNavigation;    
        }
```

And the result is:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, it is perfect. I didn't know about the `tabLayout.TabMode = TabLayout.ModeScrollable;` property.